# Perturbation theory - Differential equation

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I'm having issues understanding/solving this question I got for an exam:

Consider this nonlinear differential equation (1): $x''(t) + \cos(x(t))\cdot x(t) = \sin(t)$

Suppose $x$ is small and make an expansion of $\epsilon\cdot x$ in (1) of the form $\epsilon\cdot x = x_0\cdot \epsilon + x_1\cdot \epsilon^2 + x_2\cdot \epsilon^3 + ...$

Question: Find the equations for

- the lowest order of $\epsilon$
- the second lowest order of $\epsilon$

The equations are NOT supposed to be solved. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How have you tried to start? Did you replace $x(t)$ in the problem with $\epsilon x_0(t)+\epsilon^2 x_1(t)$?

Comment: Yes I did. Then I tried to look at the equations I would get for $O(\epsilon^0)$, $O(\epsilon)$, $O(\epsilon^2)$ and so on, but I have no idea if this is the right approach.

Comment: That's the right approach. You can use the Taylor series expansions of $\sin$ and $\cos$ (around $\epsilon=0$, not $t=0$!) to simplify the results as well.

Comment: @David:  That $\sin(t)$ is troubling me.  Won't the equation at $O(\epsilon^0)$ be $\sin (t) = 0$?  I wonder whether there's a typo in the equation.

Comment: Thanks! As far as I can tell, wouldn't the equation with the lowest order of $\epsilon$ be the equation you get for $O(\epsilon)$?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert That's specifically what's bothering me. I haven't been informed of a typo being in the equation, but that's why I'm wondering if the equation of the lowest order of $\epsilon$ would be the equation for $O(\epsilon)$?

Comment: @David: How would you use Taylor series expansion of $\cos$ around $\epsilon=0$?

Comment: $\cos(x)\approx\cos(\epsilon x_0)\approx 1-\epsilon^2x_0^2/2+\ldots$, is all you need for the first 2 equations.  Don't do anything with the $\sin(t)$ though, it has no $\epsilon$, I mistakenly thought it was $\sin(x(t))$ originally.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help!